# clearing cached version of the npm package

Tags: node.js

What does the above statement mean?I read this in one of the Github issues where the author suggests clearing the cache version of the npm app.
All I know is

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Is there any way to clear the cache of a specific node module?

Answer (score 0):

This cleans the npm cache folder.

NPM cache, as npm says is :

> npm stores cache data in an opaque directory within the configured
> cache, named _cacache. This directory is a cacache-based
> content-addressable cache that stores all http request data as well as
> other package-related data.

`npm cache clean` does not accept arguments. It is not possible to clear the cache for a specific npm package.

Here is the documentation:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-cache

Comment: npm 8.5.x does `--force`